# CSS: How to change css class of li in a navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to create a navigation menu.when i select one of it i need to change css class in to active for corresponding li.for this i have used thes code as shown

```
  <ul class="smallmenuContainer">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html#red">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#green">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#blue">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#yellow">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

   <div class="introContainer">
    <a name="red">red</a>
</div>
<div class="aboutContainer">
    <a name="green">green</a>
</div>
<div class="galleryContainer">
    <a name="blue">blue</a>
</div>
<div class="contactContainer">
</div>
<a name="yellow">yellow</a>
```

could you please help me to change the corresponding css class...

Comment: So you mean you want whichever page the user has clicked on and then navigated to to be indicated in your menu through the use of an `active` class?

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.css` function for this: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @simpe the `$.css` functions changes css properties. The poster needs `$.addClass`, `$.removeClass` or `$.toggleClass`

Comment: hi, thanks for your replay @Phil.Wheeler .I have only one page here.i want to selected menu option from the single page with color change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$(function(){
    $('.smallmenuContainer a').click(function(){
         $('.smallmenuContainer a').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

it will remove active class from all other `a` tags and add class to current `a`

Answer (score 0):

you can use removeClass and AddClass of jquery like this

```
$('.smallmenuContainer li>a').on('click',function(){
$('.smallmenuContainer li>a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont quite understand what your mean but i think this can help you :

```
$('.smallmenuContainer').click(function(
//you should put the class you want to assigne here instead of cssclass
$('#smallmenuContainer li>a').removeClass('cssclass');
$(this).addClass('cssclass');
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".smallmenuContainer a" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

Don't forget to add the css for the 'active' class.